# How set handler on scroller in javascript?

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, overflow, drop-down-menu

Problem: 
I use selectbox jquery plugin to customize select boxes on my site. Some of this select lists very big, so i decided to make them shorter, using css rules height and overflow-y:scroll. But the problem is when i try scroll by clicking on the right scroll the selectbox dissapear, it works fine if you use wheel. So the question how to prevent any javascript event handlers on this scroll, any ideas?

When people with "bad" laptops will use the boxes there is no another way to scroll - only using scrollbar, besides my employer want to have opportunity to use scrollbar

Comment: It might help if you could post a code example or demo page on jsfiddle.

Comment: @Krill - at this point you've changed the question from disabling the scroll bar and only allowing the mouse wheel to allowing both to work by resolving whatever issues you were facing. You'll need to post some code for any further help (also would be good to know what plugin you're using).

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to scroll a select box without using the scrollbars & only the mouse wheel.

http://jsfiddle.net/NiceGuy4263/eCgQx/

You'll need to tweak it a bit to get it working just right, but it demonstrates the basic principle.